# HTML Link for download mp3 support for website and Android Browser

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, download

I have created following link but which is not supporting for Android Chrome browser so It's don't download the songs. Kindly help for the same.

```
 $path='http://domain.com/admin/'.$_SESSION['video'];

 $file = $path;
<a href="<?php echo $file; ?>" download>Click To Download </a>
```

In Android Browser its directly started playing audio song once Click To Download

Comment: Can you post some code samples?

Comment: Code has been updated now and video name is coming correctly from session. Its working fine on computer,laptop browser but not on Android browsers.

Comment: what are you getting in android browser ?

Comment: Its directly started playing audio song once Click To Download

Comment: ok so you have selected default mode for video file to play, check on other mobile i think may be its downloading there and you can no do anything using php with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to force the browser to download the file, modify the HTTP headers directly. Here's a PHP code example:

```
    $path = "path/to/video.mp4";
$filename = "video.mp4";
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  // For Gecko browsers mainly
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  // Allow support for download resume
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));  // File size
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');  // Change the mime type if the file is not PDF
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);  // Make the browser display the Save As dialog
readfile($path);  // This is necessary in order to get it to actually download the file, otherwise it will be 0Kb
```

Note that this is just an extension to the HTTP protocol; some browsers might ignore it anyway.

Comment: check this video using php to force download any file type [click here (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKPPgqfjsbk)

Comment: Video help me to fix it. Thank You so much Reoxey.